# Creating a multidimensional array and adding elements to it dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create an array that displays element like below using Js/Jquery

```
0=>{[0]=>112,[1]=>'my 1st element array',[2]=>'tet1',[3]=>200}
1=>{[0]=>113,[1]=>'my 2nd element array',[2]=>'test2',[3]=>300}
2=>{[0]=>114,[1]=>'my 3rd element array',[2]=>'test3',[3]=>400}
```

Then I'll be pushing or adding elements to it dynamically.
Eg After adding my array should become like below

```
0=>{[0]=>112,[1]=>'my 1st element array',[2]=>'tet1',[3]=>200}
1=>{[0]=>113,[1]=>'my 2nd element array',[2]=>'test2',[3]=>300}
2=>{[0]=>114,[1]=>'my 3rd element array',[2]=>'test3',[3]=>400}
3=>{[0]=>115,[1]=>'my 4th element array',[2]=>'test4',[3]=>500}
```

How shall I achieve this.Any help is really appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: use .push() method to add more elements into array..

Comment: Any JavaScript tutorial about arrays will explain how to add elements to an array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Array_object

Comment: Thanks @BrijeshBhatt.But can you let me know how shall i create the array.